# Update a child table based on a logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

firstly I apologise I am really new to PHP MySQL so if I am really off track please dont grill me!

I have a membership area and two tables. The first table is the members data and the second table will hold services that the members choose.

The table layout looks like the following:

**Table: members**

id = Primary Key

username

email

etc

**Table: services**

id = Primary Key

members_id = Foreign Key

serviceone

servicetwo

etc

What I am trying to achieve at this point is to update data into the child table based on the logged in user linked by the foreign key. My PHP looks like the following:

```
<?php 

require('includes/config.php'); 

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 

//define page title
$title = 'Members Page';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 

$userId = $_SESSION['id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql3 = $db->prepare
("UPDATE services SET serviceone = :serviceone, servicetwo = :servicetwo WHERE members_id = :id");
$sql3->execute(array(
    ':serviceone' => 'variablehereoneday',
    ':servicetwo' => 'liketheabove',
    ':id' => $userId
    ));
}

?>
```

I am hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction on how the concept of updating the child table with the logged in user looking at the primary key from the members table works.

Once again sorry if I am totally off track.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not understanding, what is your question? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Hey, when I click submit the services table doesn't update with unique data based on the logged in user. It doesn't appear to do anything at this point.

Comment: Can you do `print_r($userId);` after you declare it? Just to make sure it's actually storing it. I don't see where you do `session_start()`, assuming it's somewhere in an included file.

Comment: Hey, thank you!! The issue was the id not in capitals where as the table entry is. This has printed it on the page, as well as posted in the database. Hero thank you.

Comment: Side note: `header('Location: login.php');` needs to be followed by `die();` otherwise the page will continue to execute and return data to the browser. GUI browsers will ignore it and honour the Location redirect header but a) you're still leaking sensitive data over the internet, b) a user could inspect the response before the redirect and see the sensitive data and c) non-GUI browsers / HTTP clients such as search and spam bots don't care about redirect headers and will happily slurp your supposedly private data, follow private links etc etc.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: Ok thank you ill add that in as well.